# JQuery unresponsive script error

Tags: java, ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have more than six functions like the following retrieving data to html page via server and update html which continues to run all the time when the web page is viewed. The Issue I'm having is after a while the web page pops up a warning as,

***Alert Popup Warning in Firefox***

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding.
>   You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script
>   will complete.
>
> Script: "http://../javax.faces.resource/jquery-1.7.2.js?ln=js:3983"

After getting this warning the web page functionality gets unresponsive, Is there a solution to this problem? Is it because of a issue in the way I have coded? Why is it pointing to jquery library?

***Code:***

```
function myDatapoll(){

          $.ajax({

                  type : "GET",
                  url : '../jsonData/',
                  dataType : "json",
                  async : true,
                  cache : false,

                  success: function(data) {
                            if(data!=null){
                               if($("span[id='accBal-"+data.pID+"']").length>0){

                                   $("span[id='accBal-"+data.pID+"']").text(parseFloat(data.accBal).toFixed(2));
                               }else{
                                   $("#cash").html('<span id="accBal-'+data.pID+'">'+parseFloat(data.accBal).toFixed(2)+'</span>');
                               }
                           }
                       setTimeout('myDatapoll()',1000);
                  },
                  error : function() {

                  }
             });
      }
```

Comment: A suggestion: try to debug with chrome to see where the time demanding part is (if you didn't already try)

Comment: "Is there a solution to this problem?" Yes, don't program infinite loops that load too much content to your site.

Comment: @feeela If the requirement is to retrieve data continuously every second there is no option but to do it this way, If you have a better way to do this please specify Thx.

Comment: Well, obviously your script takes to much time to execute. Have you checked manually that the desired URL exists and loads in a fair amount of time?

Comment: @feeela All the URL's exists and loads within 2ms each and all the functions work perfectly by updating html every second. Only issue is this popup coming after a while and gets the web page unresponsive

Comment: I think you mix up cause and effect here. The popup is not the reason for the unresponsibility. First the page gets unresponsive because of your JS and that is the reason why the browser allows the user to cancel that unresponsive script via a popup. Don't blame others for your mistakes. Have you read @Gabber's comment?

Comment: @feeela where have i blamed anyone?

Answer (score 2):

Just a shot: put a `setInterval` outside your function instead of the `setTimeout`:

```
setInterval('myDatapoll()',1000);

function myDatapoll(){
    //same as before but remove the setTimeout
}
```

Comment: changing it to setInterval does not stop the alert popup from invoking

Comment: A big advice: donwload something like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and test your web app communication. This might be due to a wrong url or something like that (are you sure about the url `../myData.xhtml`?)

Comment: If the URL is wrong data wont be retrieved. Here all the data is retrieved and i also can check the data on that URL which is perfectly retrieving

Comment: ok, sorry, and did you try debugging (eventually with chrome)?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use setInterval in this case. Using setInterval, myDatapoll() executes every 1000 ms regardless the request is complete or not. It will only add to the trouble. The setTimeout approach you have implemented is the right way to do it. I am not sure why you are getting that exception in Firefox.

Are you sure about the dataType? You are requesting a xhtml file and the data type is set to "json"?

Comment: although it is an xhtml file it outputs all json theres nothing else in it other than the json string

Comment: Then why not set the dataType to JSON? Though the file outputs JSON, jQuery considers it as HTML skipping the evaluation of JSON.

Comment: dataType is already set to json and the url refers to a xhtml file which returns json string all the data is also updated. There's nothing wrong with data type or the xhtml file

Comment: Yet, the file type will still be returned as XHTML and not JSON. You getting my point?

Comment: @ nairvijays what matters is data Type being set to json(i.e. correctly set in my code) so nothing matters other than that. If the data is retrieved from which ever the url(.xhtml, .html .js etc.), what matters is, is the data which is rendered in that file as an output being json. This is fully accomplished in my code. So just because some people here misunderstands this I've even changed the url to a folder like path very recently.